# EKS sc / pv / pvc status `Bound` but the Volume isn't showing in UI, AWS EBS list

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc, jenkins-x

I can't find my created Volume anywhere, I checked all the AWS-EU zones and nothing.

Here is my YAML:

```
# apiVersion: v1
# kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
# metadata:
#   name: m1-operation-volume-pvc
#   annotations:
#     volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: retain-aws-storage-class
# spec:
#   accessModes:
#   - ReadWriteMany
#   resources:
#     requests:
#         storage: 50Gi

# ---

# kind: PersistentVolume
# apiVersion: v1
# metadata:
#   name: m1-operation-persistent-volume
#   labels:
#     type: local
# spec:
#   storageClassName: retain-aws-storage-class
#   capacity:
#     storage: 50Gi
#   accessModes:
#     - ReadWriteMany
#   hostPath:
#     path: "/mnt/m1-persistent-volume"


# ---

# apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
# kind: StorageClass
# metadata:
#   name: retain-aws-storage-class
# parameters:
#   type: gp2
#   zone: eu-west-1
#   fsType: ext4
# provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
# reclaimPolicy: Retain
# allowVolumeExpansion: true
# mountOptions:
#   - debug
# volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

as you can see my `StorageClass` has a parameter `zone: eu-west-1` but no 50Gi Volume in that zone at all. Can anybody explain what could cause this issue?

```
kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                    STORAGECLASS               REASON   AGE
m1-operation-persistent-volume            50Gi       RWX            Retain           Bound    jx-develop/m1-operation-volume-pvc      retain-aws-storage-class            8h
```

and

```
kubectl get pvc
NAME                       STATUS   VOLUME                            CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS               AGE
m1-operation-volume-pvc   Bound    m1-operation-persistent-volume   50Gi       RWX            retain-aws-storage-class   8h
```

My guessing is maybe `gp2` doesn't like `- ReadWriteMany` thing or maybe my pod is not fully up and running and that's why it didn't create the Volume? But says STATUS `Bound` means it's created and Bounded...
Deployment values under spec.containers:

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: "/mnt/m1-persistent-volume"
  name: "m1-operation-volume"
```

and

```
  volumes:
  - name: m1-operation-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: m1-operation-volume-pvc
```

My `pod` :

```
kubectl get pods
jx-m1-operations-***-**        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   127        8h
```

When I am describing the `pod` fails because of `Readiness` and `Liveness` probe `/health` check, it's app-related, not Volume...

I still need to see it under `ELASTIC BLOCK STORE` AWS-UI list of Volumes.

Any ideas, where is my Volume? Or maybe it's allocated from EKS cluster resources(locally)...?